# Kotlin Media Player: How to get the filename of a resource id (resid)?

Tags: kotlin, android-mediaplayer, filenames, resource-id

I'm using the MediaPLayer to play the following mp3-file via the resid, e.g. 2131623940:
Abstract of the code:

```
                if (mp == null) {
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, 2131623940)
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "ID: ${mp!!.audioSessionId}")
                    initializeSeekBar()
                }
```

I can manually find the name of the resource file at
R.raw.bb_einfuehrung
--> As you can see, for the resid 2131623940 it is "bb_einfuehrung".

Question:
How can I get, for each resid number, the corresponding resource file name?
I found an answer on that for Java but not for Kotlin. Thank You very mich in andvance.

MediaPlayer.TrackInfo.MEDIA_TRACK_TYPE_AUDIO
only returns a number, but not the name of the track.